# Generate class and sequence diagrams

Tags: class, diagram

I need a tool to generate class and sequence diagrams for my apex classes.

I tried Objectaid but it does not generate class diagrams perfectly. I see some random variable/ method names because of slight difference in the syntax between java and apex.

ApexUml package fails in my dev org because of huge number of apex classes.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: In my experience, class diagrams extracted from all classes in a large code base are not useful with references to commonly used utility classes dominating and the overall diagram looking like a plate of spaghetti. And even when classes are moved around manually to make more sense, you still have the problem of how to display or print a huge diagram. You don't explain why you want to generate the diagrams, but if it is to help others understand your code base, a [series of smaller diagrams](http://bellekens.com/2012/02/21/uml-best-practice-5-rules-for-better-uml-diagrams/) may work better.

Comment: Those classes were developed by someone else and I wanted to understand their relationship so that I could do some refactoring/optimization work. Thanks for UML best practices link. Really useful!

Comment: In that case I think you will find the class and sequence diagrams of limited benefit. I'd start instead by looking for patterns in the class names and method names and write up some general notes with perhaps the occasional class diagram. And if refactoring is the aim, I'd pay particular attention to whether the tests are just token code coverage or actually do assert important behaviour.